# PostGreSQL Authentication Failure with "trust" option

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, postgresql

I'm trying to setup a PostGIS db using PostGreSQL 9.1 on Ubuntu 12.04.  I've set up the database, created a user account "jay" with no password, added spatial functionality following [section 2.5 here](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.5/ch02.html), and set my  pg_hba.conf for `local` to:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
```

I can can connect to the database using the PGAdminIII, requiring no password to connect, but connection fails when I try to connect via PostGIS or with QuantumGIS.  Here's a screencap of the connection window in QuantumGIS:
[image: PostGIS connection]

Looking into the problem a bit, I came across [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/38937/how-to-connect-to-postgres-with-qgis) which led me to try connecting via the terminal using `psql -U jay -h localhost gis`.  `psql` prompted me for a password, I hit enter because I had not set a password, and it returned `psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied`.  I tried again, this time supplying my Ubuntu user password, which returned

```
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "jay"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "jay"
```

I then tried setting a password for `jay` using `ALTER USER`, and entering this password in the prompt, and this failed as well.  Clearly, I am unable to connect.  However, I'm having trouble figuring out what troubleshooting steps to take next.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PostgreSQL supports two different transports for connections: TCP/IP network sockets, and unix domain sockets. *These are configured with different entries in `pg_hba.conf`*.

unix domain socket connections are the `local` entries, and TCP/IP sockets are the `host`, `hostssl` and `hostnossl` entries, as per the [`pg_hba.conf` documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).

In this case it seems highly likely that you've set `local` connections to `trust` but left TCP/IP `host` entries as `md5`. If your PostGIS tools are using TCP/IP to localhost instead of unix sockets then they'd be expected to supply a password. Some client libraries (like PgJDBC) don't support unix sockets and some programs will default to TCP/IP even if their client library supports unix sockets, so this isn't something you can control.

Make sure you have a `host` entry for `127.0.0.1/32` with `trust` auth and do a `pg_ctl reload` or otherwise reload/restart Pg.

BTW, please don't use `trust` when you move into production. It's OK for local access to test databases with no important data but that's about it.